# display image in gridview column

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have gridview in which I'm trying to display an image in each row. the process it pretty simple ie in the codebehind I populate a datatable with records, define the gridview columns(this has to be done in codebehind and not in the aspx file due to reasons beyond my control) and bind the datatable to the gridview. What Im unable to do is bind an imagecolumn to a url that generates an image as shown below

```
    Dim table As New DataTable

    table.Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Preview", GetType(Image))
 
    Dim Description As String = String.Empty
    Dim Preview As byte()
    

    Dim JSONObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Series))(result)

    For Each series As Series In JSONObj

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(series.MainDicomTags.SeriesDescription) Then
            Description= "N/A"
        Else
            Description= Replace(Replace(series.MainDicomTags.SeriesDescription.ToString(), "<", String.Empty), ">", String.Empty)
        End If

        'the image url will be different for each row...here Im using the same one for each row for testing
        table.Rows.Add(Description, byteArrayToImage(GetImageFromUrlUsingHttpWebRequest("http://localhost:8042/instances/c7cf2cec-d4ba0dd2-10b24dbb-dc47df4b-5c5a52c1/preview")))

    Next
    
    
    
    grvSeries.Columns.Clear()

    Dim bfDescription As BoundField = New BoundField()
    bfDescription.DataField = "Description"
    bfDescription.HeaderText = "Description"
    bfDescription.SortExpression = "Description"
    bfDescription.ItemStyle.Wrap = False
    grvSeries.Columns.Add(bfDescription)

    Dim bfpreview As ImageField = New ImageField()
    bfpreview.DataImageUrlField = "Preview"
    bfpreview.HeaderText = "Preview Image"
    grvSeries.Columns.Add(bfpreview)


    grvSeries.DataSource = table
    grvSeries.DataBind()
```

An example of the url is given below:

http://localhost:8042/instances/c7cf2cec-d4ba0dd2-10b24dbb-dc47df4b-5c5a52c1/preview

I cant just assign the url to the "Preview" column in the datatable as accessing the image via the url requires http authentication so I'm using the function below to fetch the image:

```
Public Function GetImageFromUrl(url As String) As Byte()
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UN").ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PW").ToString())
        request.Method = "GET"

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
        stream.CopyTo(ms)
        Return ms.ToArray()
    End Function
```

Unfortunately this isn't working and all I get a blank placeholder where the images should be.

Comment: So you telling me you can't use pre-defined columns in the markup, AND THEN post some code that hard codes the column names? Really? That does not make sense! So, you can't define the columns, and then you post code in which you hard code the column names? Hum....

Comment: dude, we can't access "http://localhost:8042/", which is only accessible by you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few confused problems here, in your code, it seems that you're loading the image bytes?

Are you sure that you want to write the bytes as image?

I assume that you're getting the URL of the image.

another thing is you're using GridView, but you build the GridView dynamically in code behind, which means you're not using it's ViewState function. This will lose the purpose of using GridView.

Then in this case, I would suggest you simply just write a normal html table rather than GridView.

Here's an example of building normal html table:

At the front page, replace your `GridView` with a `placeholder`:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then at the code behind:

```
Dim JSONObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Series))(result)

Dim htmlTable As New StringBuilder()
htmlTable.AppendLine("<table>")
htmlTable.AppendLine("<tr>")
htmlTable.AppendLine("<th>Description</th>")
htmlTable.AppendLine("<th>Preview</th>")
htmlTable.AppendLine("</tr>")

For Each series As Series In JSONObj
    Dim description As String = String.Empty
    Dim preview As String = String.Empty

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(series.MainDicomTags.SeriesDescription) Then
        description = "N/A"
    Else
        description = Replace(Replace(series.MainDicomTags.SeriesDescription.ToString(), "<", String.Empty), ">", String.Empty)
    End If

    ' Edit this line for how you get the img source
    preview = $"<img src='{series.MainDicomTags.ImgUrl}' />"

    htmlTable.AppendLine("<tr>")
    htmlTable.AppendLine($"<td>{description}</td>")
    htmlTable.AppendLine($"<td>{preview}</td>")
    htmlTable.AppendLine("</tr>")
Next

htmlTable.AppendLine("</table>")

Dim finalHtml As String = htmlTable.ToString()
```

Then fill the html table to the front end's `placeholder`:

For example:

```
Dim literalControl As New LiteralControl(finalHtml)
ph1.Controls.Add(literalControl)
```

and IF you truly obtaining the bytes of an img from your JSON objects and stored the image bytes into the variable `Preview`, then you can encode the bytes into base64 data to be displayed to the front end. Example:

```
For Each series As Series In JSONObj

    ' getting images bytes from the JSON objects
    Dim Preview As Byte() = 

    ' Convert the byte array to base64 encoded data
    Dim base64Data As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Preview) 

    ' Create the img src attribute with the base64 data
    Dim imgSrc As String = $"data:image/png;base64,{base64Data}" 

    ' Create the complete <img> tag
    Dim imgTag As String = $"<img src='{imgSrc}' />" 

Next
```

Note: Code not tested, might contain bugs.

You can further limit the size of the Image by applying CSS:

```
.imgPreview {
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

Then, write the CSS class into the `<img>` tag:

```
Dim imgTag As String = $"<img src='{imgSrc}' class='imgPreview' />" 
' or
Dim preview As String = $"<img src='{series.MainDicomTags.ImgUrl}' class='imgPreview' />"
```